# Cpufrequtils not functioning after Intel P-State is Disabled

Tags: 14.04, cpufreq

I have an Intel i9-7980XE processor. The application that I am trying to run requires me to switch off the Intel P-States and C-States. I do it via modifying the following:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="no splash intel_pstate=disable processor.max_cstate=1 intel_idle.max_cstate=0 idle=poll"
```

inside /etc/default/grub.

Then it requires me to install cpufrequtils and set the governor to performance via adding the following line inside sudo vi /etc/default/cpufrequtils:

```
GOVERNOR="performance"
```

After disabling the P-states and trying to restart cpufrequtils, I get the following:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/cpufrequtils restart
 * CPUFreq Utilities: Setting performance CPUFreq governor...                                                                                                                                                 * disabled, governor not available... 

cpufreq-info
cpufrequtils 008: cpufreq-info (C) Dominik Brodowski 2004-2009
Report errors and bugs to cpufreq@vger.kernel.org, please.
analyzing CPU 0:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 1:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 2:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 3:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 4:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 5:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 6:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 7:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 8:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 9:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 10:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 11:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 12:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 13:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 14:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 15:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 16:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
analyzing CPU 17:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  maximum transition latency: 4294.55 ms.
```

I have read in many forums that the modern intel processors need to have P-State enabled to be able to do frequency scaling.

I have to use Ubuntu 14.04, since the application is proven to be stable only in this Ubuntu version.

So how can I disable P-states and still be able to set the governor to performance?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to disable the intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver.
It has a performance scaling governor (but that isn't actually relevant here).

Since you have disabled all the idle states except poll, all of your CPUs should always be always running at the maximum frequency anyhow, at least if your system can deal with all the heat generated (and it will be a lot of energy).

By the way, it is not true that the intel-pstate CPU frequency driver must be used, it is just the default and what Intel recommends. Anyone can use the acpi-cpufreq CPU scaling driver if they prefer. There is also passive mode for the intel_pstate driver, which provides all the same governors as the acpi-cpufreq driver. (However, I do not know if passive mode has been backported to whatever kernel is used in 14.04.)

Please be aware that support for 14.04 ends in about month.